# select query performance Vs primary,foreign key

Tags: oracle, referential-integrity

i have copied the table structure(without primary and foreign key constraint),data,index(all indexes) from one schema to another schema .

While trying to run a select query with multiple joins(in the new schema) , it is taking much longer time than running the same query in the old schema(with constraints).

Will the omitted foreign and primary key constraints is the reason behind this performance lag?

Comment: Look at the execution plans on both systems. Did the indexes you copied ('all' of them) include those that backed up the primary key, and did/do you have indexes on the foreign key constraints? Missing integrity constraints on their own shouldn't make a difference to performance (though they will to integrity!), but the indexes they are based on will. Also did you gather stats on the new tables?

Comment: 'All' index includes index on primary key ,foreign key columns.

Comment: Gathering stats on new tables? Pls explain me how to do that

Comment: OK, so look at both execution plans and see if they are using the indexes you expect. And check the statistics are up-to-date. Easiest way to gather statistics is to run `dbms_stats.gather_schema_stats(user)`; but if you do that I'd suggest you still look at the execution plan before and after, as well as comparing with the old system's plan.

Comment: I checked the execution plan of both the systems.. They are using different indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem with respect to performance while importing objects from one environment to another  and then I have added the missing constraints and then I could see good improvement in performance. 
Hence I would request you to please  add the constraints and then run your join query.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, primary and unique keys are also indexes (that is, the constraint is supported by an index), so missing primary or unique keys could mean missing indexes.

Also, the optimiser can apply some transformations if constraints are in place. For example, consider this query (using Oracle HR demo schema):

```
select count(*)
from   employees e
       join departments d on d.department_id = e.department_id;
```

Execution plan:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name              | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |                   |     1 |     3 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE  |                   |     1 |     3 |            |          |
|*  2 |   INDEX FULL SCAN| EMP_DEPARTMENT_IX |   106 |   318 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
   2 - filter("E"."DEPARTMENT_ID" IS NOT NULL)
```

Notice there is no reference to `departments`. The optimiser knows that a `department_id` in `employees` must exist in `departments` because there is a foreign key enforcing this, and also it can only occur once in `departments` because it's the primary key. Therefore, there is no need to actually evaluate the join, as all it needs to do is check that `e.department_id` is not null. As there is an index on that column, it can just treat the index as a skinny table and not even touch `employees`. (If `e.department_id` was defined as `not null`, it wouldn't even need that filter.)

Now see what happens if we disable the constraint:

```
SQL> alter table employees disable constraint EMP_DEPT_FK;

Table altered.

SQL> select count(*)
  2  from   employees e
  3         join departments d on d.department_id = e.department_id;

  COUNT(*)
----------
       106

SQL> @xplan
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
Compatibility is set to 12.2.0.0.0

Plan hash value: 1475840611

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name              | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |                   |     1 |     7 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE     |                   |     1 |     7 |            |          |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS      |                   |   106 |   742 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    INDEX FULL SCAN  | EMP_DEPARTMENT_IX |   107 |   321 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN| DEPT_ID_PK        |     1 |     4 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
   4 - access("D"."DEPARTMENT_ID"="E"."DEPARTMENT_ID")
```